# PostgreSQL: Inserting a column from one database into an empty column of another database

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a database named hq with a table ticket, which has a column bet_house(actually names character varying 20..). I want to get the the distinct names so, I do :

```
     select distinct bet_house from ticket
```

I have another database named Kopija that has a table Tabela(empty) that has a column kol2(character varying 50) in which I want to insert all these values in from the last query so I did this and got an error message.

```
  insert into Kopija.Tabela(kol2) (select distinct bet_house from hq.ticket)         
  ERROR: schema "kopija" does not exist
```

These databases are all under the same localhost user postgres 8.3.20 version. Command done in SQL query tool.

Comment: You can't do cross-database queries in Postgres. **Especially** not with the old, outdate, ancient and unsupported version 8.3

Comment: 8.3.20 is the version.

Comment: 8.3.x has been out of support for over 3 years now. You should upgrade to a supported version: https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/  to do cross-database queries you need to use a DbLink: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/dblink.html